# Curl gives a different response than normal browser

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use curl to get response from a web page. But I get different responses while using curl and when browsing normally.

PHP file

```
$ch = curl_init();
echo "trying<br>";
//$url = "home.iitk.ac.in/~gopi/student_search/feedback.php";
$roll_no = "11101";
$name="";
$program="all";
$department="all";
$email="";
$gender="both";
$city="";
$course="";
$order="id";
$hostel="";
$bg='';
$tile = '0';
$offset = 0;
$url = "http://search.junta.iitk.ac.in/get2.php?&tile=0&roll_no=".$roll_no."&name=".$name."
                        &program=".$program."&dept=".$department."&login=".$email."&gender=".$gender."
                        &city=".$city."&course=".$course."&hostel=".$hostel."&bg=".$bg."&offset=".$offset;
                        echo $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ret_val = curl_error($ch);
echo $result;
echo $ret_val;
curl_close($ch);
```

And this results me in this page,

[image]

But when I directly go to the same url, it gives me 44 results.

[image]

and more results.

How do I get the same result using curl?

## Edit

(doesn't work.)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://search.junta.iitk.ac.in');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the targeted server checks the user agent and if it's not a real browser it throws it a way(or generally behaves differently).

Try specifying the user agent - http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

For example:

> curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" http://www.apple.com

In PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Comment: Seems so. How do I specify the user agent in php?

Comment: I tried adding , `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://search.junta.iitk.ac.in');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`, but makes no difference.

Comment: THen you might want to check if it's necessary to have some session variables set in order to return the results. I don't see any logging in on your side. Only that comes to my mind at the moment.

Comment: Can you put the URL you're requesting to the comments, please?

Comment: I have checked my cookies and session variables after your suggestion. But nothing has been stored as I see in developers tools in chrome.

Comment: Probably that doesn't work outside the college campus. However, this is the url : http://search.junta.iitk.ac.in/get2.php?&tile=0&roll_no=11101&name=%20&program=all&dept=all&login=&gender=both%20&city=&course=&hostel=&bg=&offset=0 .Try to see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't set any variables or cookies. How do I get the response as I am getting in my browser. :( Cannot accept the answer till then.

Comment: It's hard to provide further help. I can't test it, because of the aformentioned problem. I've experienced similar problems like this one and most of them could be solved by providing the user-agent setting (especially when using search engines). Basically you want to identify what's different between those two methods of access and set your automated access like the browser/non-automated one.